# Access internal file VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I added a text file to a testapp's solution and I want to read said file.  I don't remember how to do this, I know it has to do with reflections but I need a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the text file to a .ResX file, you can have all the benefits (dynamic updating, for instance) AND not need to worry about interacting with an actual file.  VB will automatically create a class to access the file - suppose you have Resources.resx.  You can access it with My.Resources.MyFile - it will return a string.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the file as a resource? In that case you can access its (`String`) content by just using `My.Resources.name_of_file`. Otherwise, the easiest way to read a text file in VB is to use the following.

```
Dim content = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("filename")
```

Answer (score -1):

I was going to write some code, but instead found a better explanation [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets8p2.html)

In your case, you'll need to use your application path instead of "C:\".

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about embedding the text file as a resource in the solution - ie compiled in?

For that you need an instance of an assembly class (referecning yours, Assembly has a static member called GetExecutingAssembly) From there you call the GetManifestResourceStream